# is it possible to use EOD with swiftmailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm trying to use [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html) to send email. Is there a way to use EOD with it?

This syntax (from their website) seems like a really difficult way to build something in html:

```
'<html>' .
' <head></head>' .
' <body>' .
'  Here is an image <img src="' . $cid . '" alt="Image" />' .
'  Rest of message' .
' </body>' .
'</html>',
```

But when I try this

```
$msg = <<<EOD
<html>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        NAME
        </td>

        <td>
        thomas 
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        COMPANY
        </td>

        <td>
        whatever
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<html>
EOD;


   // Set the To addresses with an associative array
->setTo(array('whatever@whatever.whatever'=>'thomas'))

// Give it a body
->setBody($msg)

;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

I simply get an email with the html printed out. Is there some way to make this easier?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can strip the line breaks.

```
$msg = str_replace("\r\n","",$msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you receive an *HTML* structure in your email while using *swiftmailer*, it means you have set content as:

```
->setContentType('text/html; charset=utf-8')
```

Remove the `charset=utf-8` and let the content be `text/HTML`.
If the problem persists, review your *EOD* format.

Answer (score -1):

got to set the content type. ><

`->setContentType('text/html')`